# Как отправить 2 запроса успев попасть в 1 поток на asp на python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, запрос, requests

На сайте есть функция отправки сообщения, делается запросом - InboxMail, но если я хочу взять и отправить вместе с сообщением еще один файл, вызывается еще один запрос - FileChunkSave, который берет вытаскивает из ответа запроса InboxMail переменную messageID и прикрепляет указанный файл. Если я беру последовательно отправляю 2 запроса то сервер дает такой ответ

> unexpected end of stream, the content may have already been read by another component
> неожиданный конец потока, содержимое, возможно, уже было прочитано другим компонентом

Как я могу исправить эту ошибку "unexpected end of stream, the content may have already been read by another component"?
[image: Ошибка]

Мой код

```
import requests
import json

headers = {}

def tokenAuth():#Получаем токен
    url = "https://test.mmis.ru/api/tokenauth"
    dataLogPass = {"userName": "student", "password": "testMe"}
    response = requests.post(url, json = dataLogPass)
    response = json.loads(response.text)['data']['data']
    token = response['accessToken']
    headers.update({'Cookie':'authToken='+token})
    sendMail()

def sendMail():#Отправляем сообщение
    url = "https://test.mmis.ru/api/Mail/InboxMail"
    headers.update({'Content-Type':'application/json;charset=utf-8'})
    payload = {
        "htmlMessage":"",
        "message":"",
        "markdownMessage":"1",
        "theme":"Python",
        "userToID":[{
            "id": 1136,
            "email":"test@mail.ru",
            "fio": "Петров Петр Иванович"}]}
    payload = json.dumps(payload)
    response = requests.post(url,headers = headers, data = payload)
    messageID = json.loads(response.text)['data']["messageID"]
    del headers['Content-Type']
    FileChunkSave(messageID)

def FileChunkSave(messageID):# Сохранение файла
    url =  "https://test.mmis.ru/api/Mail/FileChunkSave"
    headers.update({'Content-Type':'multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryRCDYViXYfnieA2py'})
    files = {'testfile.docx': open(r"C:\Users\Loki\Downloads\testfile.docx", 'rb')}
    payload = {"messageID":messageID,"isFirstChunk":True,"isLastChunk":True}
    response = requests.post(url,headers=headers,data=payload,files=files)
    del headers['Content-Type']


tokenAuth()
```

Comment: Вы могли бы уменьшить Ваш пример до минимального? То, что Вы описали текстом не совсем бьётся с кодом. Пожалуйста, уточните вопрос

Comment: Уменьшил код, как вы и просили. Я не могу понять как мне отправить сообщение с файлом на сайт в виде запроса и не получить ошибку "Unexpected end of Stream..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сервер на который я отправляю в обязательном порядке требует правильно сгенерированную переменную WebKitFormBoundary для файла, то есть границы ключа.

```
def fileCoursesSave(idTask,courseTaskID):

fields = {
    'newFiles': ('testfile.docx', "multipart/form-data"),
    'file_id': "0",
    "studentID":str(data['idAdverse']),
    'courseTaskID':courseTaskID,
    'courseStudentID':idTask
}
boundary = '----WebKitFormBoundary' \
           + ''.join(random.sample(string.ascii_letters + string.digits, 16))
m = MultipartEncoder(fields=fields, boundary=boundary)

headers.update({
    "Host": "test.mmis.ru",
    "Connection": "keep-alive",
    "Content-Type": m.content_type
})
req = requests.post(host+"/api/ElectronicEducation/FileSave",headers=headers,data=m)
print(req.text)
```